# jquery and attr, undefind

Tags: jquery, attributes

Whats wrong with my code?  Why does `.atrr()` show empty?
Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#push').click(function(){
      alert($('#push2').attr('href').val);
   }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="push">PUSH</div>
<a id="push2" href="http://www.google.com">PUSH Google</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) *already* returns a string, so just use it directly (without the `.val`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#push').click(function(){
        alert($('#push2').attr('href'));
    }); 
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/p3zyE/).  The reason you see `undefined` currently is because the `.val` property of a **string** object *is* `undefined` :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need `.val` after `$('#push2').attr('href')`. `attr` function already returns string.

Comment: fast, fiver replies in one minute :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#push2').attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure you need the .val after the attr. function? Try that and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alert($('#push2').attr('href').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your using the same id for the div and for the anchor. Ids must be unique. Jquery pulls the first element which is the div and yes that div doesn't have an href</s>
Just use $('#push2').attr('href');